# Como exibir os posts recentes do WordPress em uma página

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Eu encontrei uma forma de exibir os artigos do WordPress com o seguinte código.

```
<ul> 
    <?php 
    $recent = new WP_Query("cat=3&showposts=5"); 
    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?> 
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li> 
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
</ul>
```

O tutorial completo se encontra [aqui](http://www.tudoparawordpress.com.br/wordpress-plugins/como-exibir-os-posts-recentes-de-uma-categoria-especifica-usando-widgets/). Já tinha encontrado um script para Blogger, mas ele não funciona no WordPress.

No tutorial tambem tem esse outro codigo que é para mostra a imagem do post.

```
<a href=""><img src="/timthumb.php?src=&h=60&w=60&zc=1" title="Clique para ler: " alt="" class="recent-posts-thumb" width="60px" height="60px" />
```

O objetivo é mostrar uma página com artigos de determinado artigo: Categoria ou tag. E assim conseguir organizá-los melhor.

O nome desse codigo seria um hack *Leia mais*.  O que gostaria é mostrar artigos especificos com um pequeno resumo do post  em uma página.

Comment: **Por favor**, confira o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help . . . . Quando você edita aqui no [pt.so] tem um box de ***preview*** logo abaixo, dá pra ver claramente que o código não está aparecendo.

Comment: Eu adiciono o html normal, mas ele não aparece, fica cortando varias partes.

Comment: Confira minha edição para ver como formatar aqui no SOPT: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/30997/revisions . . . Sugiro que você instale um corretor ortográfico no seu browser, isso diminui muito o trabalho dos editores.

Comment: PS: formatei o código pra ficar legível, tudo em uma linha só não é nada legal pro entendimento... Mas conferindo agora vejo que não tem diferença nos dois primeiro blocos de código. Pode [edit] sua pergunta e esclarecer isso?+

Comment: Retirei o bloco que era igual o primeiro.

Comment: Tinha um bug no código do plugin, consertei. Chegou a testar alguma das soluções?

Answer (score 1):

Tem duas maneiras de fazer isso.

## [Page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

Crie um arquivo dentro do seu tema, usando como base o `page.php` e colocando um nome como `recentes-page.php`. Troque o cabeçalho PHP para:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Posts recentes
*/
```

<kbd>[image] <-- aparecerá *Posts recentes* no lugar do *My Custom Page*</kbd>

Agora é só adaptar seu código nesse template, criar uma página nova e selecionar o novo template `Posts recentes`.

## [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Crie um plugin que vai gerar o resultado quando adicionar `[meu_shortcode]` em qualquer post, página ou widget. Como um shortcode tem que retornar o resultado em vez de imprimir, é melhor usar `get_posts` ao invés de `WP_Query`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Shortcode para Posts recentes
 * Plugin URI:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31002/201
 * Description: Use o shortcode [recentes] para mostrar uma lista de posts recentes
 * Author:      brasofilo   
 */

/**
 * Permite o uso de shortcodes no Widget de Texto
 */
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
 
/**
 * Declaração do shortcode
 */ 
add_shortcode( 'recentes', 'shortcode_sopt_30997' );

/**
 * Callback do shortcode [recentes]
 */
function shortcode_sopt_30997( $atts, $content = null ) 
{
    $html = '<ul>';
    $recent = get_posts("cat=3&showposts=5"); 
    
    if( !$recent )
        return 'Não há posts recentes';
        
    foreach( $recent as $post )
    {
        $html .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',
            get_permalink( $post->ID ),
            $post->post_title
            );
    }
    
    $html .= '</ul>';
    
    return $html;
}
```

---

Posts relacionados:

- [*When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)
- [*Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)